# PassportJS No Method authenticate

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I am running into an issue where I am trying to access my passport functions from my separate config file, but it doesn't appear that passport is being exposed when I require the file in my routes file. The error is occurring at `.post(passportConfig.authenticate('local-login', {`

Error:

> has no method 'authenticate'
>           at Object. (/Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node/user-app/app/controllers/site-routes.js:68:23)`

passport.js (Passport authentication logic):

```
module.exports = function(passport){

var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var models = require('../models/db-index');

/*====  Passport Configuration  ====*/

// Serialize sessions
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    console.log(user.user_id + "Serializing");
  done(null, user.user_id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(user_id, done) {
  models.User.findById(user_id).then(function(user){
    done(null, user);
  }).error(function(err){
    done(err, null);
  });
});

//Login Logic

passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password',
    passReqToCallback: true
},
function(req, email, password, done){
    models.User.findOne({ where: { email : email }}).then(function(user) {
        if (!user) {
            done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Unknown User'));
        } else if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
            done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Wrong password'));
        } else {
            done(null, user);
        }
    }).catch(function(e) {
        done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', e.name + " " + e.message));
    });
}));

//Sign up Logic

passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password',
    passReqToCallback: true
}, function(req, email, password, done){
    models.User.findOne({ where: { email: email }}).then(function(existingUser){
        if (existingUser)
            return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'That email is already taken.'));
        if (req.user) {
            var user = req.user;
            user.email = email;
            user.password = models.User.generateHash(password);
            user.save().catch(function (err){
                throw err;
            }).then(function(){
                done(null, user);
            });
        } else {
            var newUser = User.build({
                email: email,
                password: models.User.generateHash(password)
            });

            newUser.save().then(function(){ done(null, newUser);
            }).catch(function(err){
                done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', err));
            });
        }
    }).catch(function(e){
        done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage',e.name + " " + e.message));
    })

}));




};
```

site-routes.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var siteRoutes  = express.Router();
var path = require('path');
var passportConfig = require(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..','./config/passport.js'));
var models = require('../models/db-index');

/*====  Index   ====*/

siteRoutes.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('pages/index.hbs');
});

siteRoutes.get('/flash', function(req, res){
    req.flash('test', 'it worked');
    res.redirect('/')
});

/*====  Login   ====*/


siteRoutes.route('/login')

    .get(function(req, res){
        res.render('pages/login.hbs');
    })

    .post(passportConfig.authenticate('local-login', {
        successRedirect: '/app',
        failureRedirect: '/login',
        failureFlash: 'Invalid username or password.'
    }));



siteRoutes.route('/sign-up')

    .get(function(req, res){
        res.render('pages/sign-up.hbs');
    })

    .post(function(req, res){

        models.User.create({
            firstName: req.body.firstName,
            lastName: req.body.lastName,
            email: req.body.email,
            password: req.body.password
        }).then(function() { 
            res.redirect('/app');
        //res.redirect('/sign-up/create-organization');
    }).catch(function(error){
        res.send(error);
    })

    });
module.exports = siteRoutes;
```

Comment: Which version? IIRC, 0.3.0 is broken

Comment: "passport": "^0.3.2", "passport-local": "^1.0.0", I think it is more of a issue with my javascript since it isn't recognizing where I require passport in passport.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `require` `config/passport.js`, `passportConfig` will be initialized as a function, as you assigned a function to `module.exports` in your `passport.js` file. I'm referring to this line:

```
module.exports = function(passport){
```

What I'd do is to get rid of the function. Let the code execute and then assign `passport` to `module.exports`. `.authenticate` method is sitting on `passport` object.

Like this:

```
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var models = require('../models/db-index');

/*====  Passport Configuration  ====*/

// Serialize sessions
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    console.log(user.user_id + "Serializing");
  done(null, user.user_id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(user_id, done) {
  models.User.findById(user_id).then(function(user){
    done(null, user);
  }).error(function(err){
    done(err, null);
  });
});

//Login Logic

passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password',
    passReqToCallback: true
},
function(req, email, password, done){
    models.User.findOne({ where: { email : email }}).then(function(user) {
        if (!user) {
            done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Unknown User'));
        } else if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
            done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Wrong password'));
        } else {
            done(null, user);
        }
    }).catch(function(e) {
        done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', e.name + " " + e.message));
    });
}));

//Sign up Logic

passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password',
    passReqToCallback: true
}, function(req, email, password, done){
    models.User.findOne({ where: { email: email }}).then(function(existingUser){
        if (existingUser)
            return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'That email is already taken.'));
        if (req.user) {
            var user = req.user;
            user.email = email;
            user.password = models.User.generateHash(password);
            user.save().catch(function (err){
                throw err;
            }).then(function(){
                done(null, user);
            });
        } else {
            var newUser = User.build({
                email: email,
                password: models.User.generateHash(password)
            });

            newUser.save().then(function(){ done(null, newUser);
            }).catch(function(err){
                done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', err));
            });
        }
    }).catch(function(e){
        done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage',e.name + " " + e.message));
    })

}));


module.exports = passport;
```